# How to serialize a composite object with jackson custom serializer?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, jackson

I saw this [post](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) about jackson custom serializer.

What is the difference purpose between `jackson.jar` and `jersey.jar`?
Is there a way to create a custom serlializer to non-falt obj (aka composite object) ?

Comment: I guess you mean "custom", not "costume" ;) (just edited).

Comment: For the first question the answer can be found by hovering the mouse over the tags in your own post. For the second one(which is unclearly stated) the answer is in the link you provided.